# How to ignore whitespace and carriage returns within text using regular expressions

Tags: php, expression, pcre

Im quite new to stackoverflow so I dont know if this question has been asked before, but I cant seem to find any past questions which hint at the answer. Any help is really appreciated and thanks in advance.

I have this text:

```
{
   1282837200, -- [1]
   "Type", -- [2]
   "Name", -- [3]
   "Reason", -- [4]
   Amount, -- [5]
  }, -- [1]
  {
   1282838220, -- [1]
   "Type", -- [2]
   "Name", -- [3]
   "Reason", -- [4]
   Amount, -- [5]
  }, -- [2]
```

Which I need to create a regular expression for and extract the necessary data. I understand how to extract data from source files using regular expressions within PHP, using source text which has no "whitespace" or carriage returns.

But I need help with creating an expression which includes the whitespace etc. included within this source.

Comment: Now the source text has been posted, stackoverflow has essentially removed a lot of the whitespace

Comment: i'm confused. if the above text is the source, where do you want the whitespaces inserted? what should the output look like?

Comment: what exactly are you trying to match in the text (what is "necessary data")? What regex have you tried? It might be easier to change the regex to match the text you want instead of matching spaces/newlines. For example something as simple as `/[\w\d]+/im` might do what you want or at least get you started.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`\s` is the symbol for whitespace, which may or may not include newlines, anyway there's `[\r\n]` for them, ignore these and that's it. You could also tell what exactly you want to do or even post the regex you have so far so I can help you further if you want.

EDIT: I'm just guessing, the regexp you want may be this:

```
/\s*{[\s\n\r]*^\s*(\d+).*[\s\n\r]*^\s*"([^"]+)".*[\s\n\r]*^\s*"([^"]+)".*[\s\n\r]*^\s*"([^"]+)".*[\s\n\r]*^\s*(\w+).*[\s\n\r]*^\s*},.*[\s\n\r]*^/m
```

This matches one block and disregards the numbers in brackers. `/m` switch triggers multiline mode.

Answer (score 0):

If you're trying to simply remove all whitespace, try the following:
`$string = preg_replace('/\s+/s', '', $string);`.

`\s+` matches one or more spaces, tabs, and newlines. The `s` in `/s` tells the regex to look at the string as a whole as opposed to one line at a time.